# pie chart drawing for a specific column in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a dataframe df, which has many columns. In df["house_electricity"], there are values like 1,0 or blank/NA. I want to plot the column in terms of a pie chart, where percentage of only 1 and 0 will be shown. Similarly I want to plot another pie chart where percentage of 1,0 and blank/N.A all will be there.

| customer_id | house_electricity | house_refrigerator |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cid01 | 0 | 0 |
| cid02 | 1 | na |
| cid03 |  | 1 |
| cid04 | 1 |  |
| cid05 | na | 0 |

```
#I wrote the following but it didnt give my my expected result
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.read_csv("my_file.csv")

df_col=df.columns



df["house_electricity"].plot(kind="pie")
```

```
#I wrote the following but it didnt give my my expected result
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.read_csv("my_file.csv")

df_col=df.columns



df["house_electricity"].plot(kind="pie")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,0,np.nan,1,1,1,'',0,0,np.nan]})
df

a
0   1
1   0
2   NaN
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   
7   0
8   0
9   NaN
```

The code below will give

```
df["a"].value_counts(dropna=False).plot(kind="pie")
```

[image]

If you want combine na and empty value, try replacing empty values with np.nan, then try to plot

```
df["a"].replace("", np.nan).value_counts(dropna=False).plot(kind="pie")
```

[image]

Comment: why 4 blocks are being shown? I want three blocks to be shown in the chart (for 1,0 and blank+nan). Or just two blocks(only for 1 and 0)

Comment: in that case use df["a"].replace("", np.nan).value_counts(dropna=False).plot(kind="pie")

Comment: please vote my question if you liked it

Answer (score 0):

For solution you need to try with this code to generate 3 blocks.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'customer_id': ['cid01', 'cid02', 'cid03', 'cid04', 'cid05'],
        'house_electricity': [0, 1, None, 1, None],
        'house_refrigerator': [0, None, 1, None, 0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

counts = df['house_electricity'].value_counts(dropna=False)
counts.plot.pie(autopct='%1.1f%%', labels=['0', '1', 'NaN'], shadow=True)

plt.title('Percentage distribution of house_electricity column')

plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: If it is helpful then you can flag as right answer and upvote it for other users too.

Comment: Hi, the first answer is also right, so I accepted it as the answer.

Comment: please vote my question if you liked it